# Getting count of a specific document viewed in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to get total count of document viewed in SharePoint Online?

Also is it possible to get total number of times a document is searched?

Answer (score 2):

You can use auditing to get the number of views for each document.

Auditing in SharePoint online for your reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-audit-data-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2?CTT=5&origin=HA102772739&CorrelationId=6e6bf989-1eee-4b40-a7c2-a84a06b9b6c4&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102866204

You can get the Number of Queries performed.

View search usage reports on SharePoint Online:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/view-search-usage-reports

Comment: Is there any API to get such details?